# Trackear ScreenView como PageView - Google Analytics

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics

estoy haciendo un trackeo de una Aplicación nativa de Android, pero quiero que las `ScreenView` poderlas enviar como `PageView`, esto lo estoy haciendo con **Google Tag Manager** como intermediario y caigan a una `UA` de **Google Analytics**.
No tengo problemas al trackear `Events` pero por alguna razón no me deja trackear algo como `PageView`.

Actualmente estoy haciendo esto:

```
mAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW) {
   param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName)
   param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, "MainActivity")
}
```

Sé que la manera correcta sería enviarlas con Firebase directo a Analytics, pero quisiera saber si hay manera de hacer un registro como PageView desde una aplicación nativa.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener un registro al visualizar tu pantalla lo realizas como lo estas exponiendo:

```
mAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SCREEN_VIEW) {
   param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_NAME, screenName)
   param(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCREEN_CLASS, "MainActivity")
}
```

Si es que no se registra es debido a que esto no es instantáneo, revisa:
["¿Cuánto tiempo tardan en aparecer mis datos de Firebase Analytics?"](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/how-long-does-it-take-for-my-firebase-analytics-data-to-show-up.html)
pero aún más importante, los registros personalizados son sin costo pero el consultarlos tiene un precio :-/, te sugiero revisar:

https://firebase.google.com/pricing?hl=es-419

Recuerda también que con el simple hecho de implementar el SDK en tu app, puedes ver también esta información como evento "screen view".

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]